# Remove question mark following period for reference title in PDF, using Vancouver.bst

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

I am using LyX with a slightly modified `vancouver.bst` file. In the PDF output, reference titles that end with a question mark have a period also printed.  This occurs only for those references that use the "misc" entry type.  For example, one output is:

> U. S. Geological Survey. Forecasting California’s Earthquakes—What Can
>      We Expect in the Next 30 Years?. 2008.

Note the "?." following the title.

The entry for this reference is:

```
@Misc{USG08,
  Author         = {{U.S. Geological Survey}},
  Title          = {Forecasting {C}alifornia's {E}arthquakes---{W}hat
                   {C}an {W}e {E}xpect in the {N}ext 30 {Y}ears?},
  year           = 2008
}
```

You can find the [modified version of `vancouver.bst` on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/b9Rwhxd3).

I have read the responses to a similar question "remove comma after title ending with questionmark."  But I could not get any of the ideas there to work, or I did not implement them properly.  I do not understand bst files very well.

Can anyone offer hacks to the `.bst` file that would remove the extra periods?

Comment: bibtex can't process "backwards", so unless the question mark is input in a special way that will "redirect" bibtex, a change in the `.bst` file isn't likely to be practical.  you might attack this from the tex angle: define `\newcommand{\killpunct}[1]{}` and add `\killpunct` immediately after the `?`.  (`\nopunct` is already defined in a way that won't work here, and `\@gobble` contains an `@` that isn't practical in normal input.)  not tested.

Comment: Thanks.  The information is helpful, but the approach did not appear to work for me.  I added "\newcommand{\killpunct}[1]{}" to the LaTeX preamble, and added "\killpunct" immediately after a question mark in my .bib file.  But I received errors on trying to compile. I also tried adding "{\killpunct}" after a question mark in the .bib file, but that also gave errors.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6):

here's a hack that does raise some warnings in bibtex, but appears to produce the desired output.

in this test file, i added a definition for `\killpunct`, to ignore the next token in
the input, which will be the (inserted by bibtex) period.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\killpunct}[1]{}
\begin{document}
This is a citation for \cite{USG08}.

\bibliographystyle{modified_vancouver}
\bibliography{bibpunct}
\end{document}
```

i made one change to the bib entry -- adding `\killpunct` after the question mark in the title -- and called the file `bibpunct.bib`:

```
@Misc{USG08,
  Author         = {{U.S. Geological Survey}},
  Title          = {Forecasting {C}alifornia's {E}arthquakes---{W}hat
                   {C}an {W}e {E}xpect in the {N}ext 30 {Y}ears?\killpunct},
  year           = 2008
}
```

note that there are no extra braces around `\killpunct`.

here is the output:

[image]

the bibtex run *did* raise some warnings:

```
Warning--empty author and editor in USG08
Warning--missing publisher in USG08
```

i didn't explore `modified_vancouver.bst` to see what might be causing this; there's
nothing wrong that i can see with the `author` field in the `.bib` input.  if this
were my project, i would look for documentation on the `.bst` file, or try to ask its
author what is expected from a `@misc` entry.