# In a reference: how to remove the comma when the paper title ends with a question mark

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation

I use the `jf.bst` bibliography style and the `jf.sty` package. I am trying to solve two issues related to the formatting of bibliographic entries.

**1.** How to remove the comma after the title field if the title ends with a question mark?

**e.g.**

**It's shown as:** Bollen, Nicolas PB, and Robert E Whaley, 2004, Does net buying pressure affect the shape of implied volatility **functions?,** *Journal of Finance 59*, 711–753.

**I need it to be:** Bollen, Nicolas PB, and Robert E Whaley, 2004, Does net buying pressure affect the shape of implied volatility **functions?** *Journal of Finance 59*, 711–753.

**2.** How to remove the space between the journal and the final full stop if the paper is a working paper without publication information.

**e.g.**

**It's shown as:** Mellow, Craig, 2018, July 11, China finds a slower, steadier growth path, ***Barron's .***

**I need it to be:** Mellow, Craig, 2018, July 11, China finds a slower, steadier growth path, ***Barron's.***

Comment: Are you able to switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`? These issues are very easy to fix in `biblatex`, but a pain to fix in a `bst` file. From my quick look, it seems like the *Journal of Finance* just wants PDFs submitted, not TeX source. And if you're not submitting to any journal, then `biblatex` can be an option. If so, perhaps [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/379901/87678) might be helpful. You'd have to modify `jf.sty` from using `natbib` to `biblatex` though as they are not compatible.

Comment: @DavidPurton - What evidence do you have that the OP is using the `natbib` package? All he/she has indicated is that the `jf` package is in use.

Comment: @Iris - Please indicate from where you obtained `jf.sty` and `jf.bst`. (They don't seem to be part of the TeXLive distribution.) Various forms of these files are known to exist, and not all are created equally. Separately: Why do you use the `@article` entry type for a piece that wasn't published in an academic journal? For sure, you should be getting warnings from BibTeX about missing `volume` and `number` fields. Depending on the type of the working paper, you should be using entry types such as `@techreport`, `@unpublished`, and `@misc`.

Comment: @Mico, just a guess. But since JF style is author year, it's likely enough.

Answer (score 3):

## `natbib` solution

Here's a dodgy hack based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181298/87678). It's easy and will give you the results you need in a hurry. But, a better solution would be to either fix the `bst` file or move to `biblatex` (below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bollen+whaley:2004,
  author = {Bollen, Nicolas PB and Whaley, Robert E},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Does Net Buying Pressure Affect the Shape of Implied Volatility Functions?\killpunct},
  journal = {Journal of Finance},
  volume = {59},
  pages = {711-753}
}
@unpublished{mellow:2018,
  author = {Mellow, Craig},
  year = {2018},
  title = {July 11, {China} Finds a Slower, Steadier Growth Path, {Barron's}.\killpunct}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand{\killpunct}[1]{}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{jf}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## `biblatex` solution

For reference, this should get you started in `biblatex`. More code, but more flexibility. And doesn't involve abusing fields in `bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bollen+whaley:2004,
  author = {Bollen, Nicolas PB and Whaley, Robert E},
  date = {2004},
  title = {Does Net Buying Pressure Affect the Shape of Implied Volatility Functions?},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Finance},
  volume = {59},
  pages = {711-753}
}
@unpublished{mellow:2018,
  author = {Mellow, Craig},
  date = {2018-07-11},
  title = {{China} Finds a Slower, Steadier Growth Path, {Barron's}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{volume}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printdateextra}}
\newbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#1}
      {}
      {\printfield{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space
          \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
          \iffieldundef{#3}
            {}
            {\nobreakspace
             \stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}}}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the approach of biblatex as well for future reference?

Comment: @Diaa, there is an existing answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/379906/87678